# Looping through multiline CSV rows in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following csv file with 3 columns:

```
row1value1,row1value2,"row1
multi
line
value"
row2value1,row2value2,"row2
multi
line
value"
```

Is there a way to loop through its rows like (this does not work, it reads lines):

```
while read $ROW
do
#some code that uses $ROW variable
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Use CVS parsers available in PGP, Python, Perl etc

Comment: I know there are available solutions but I'm trying to find out if this is possible in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can do this using `FPAT`:

```
awk -v RS='"\n' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{
    print "Record #", NR, " =======>"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       sub(/^"/, "", $i)
       printf "Field # %d, value=[%s]\n", i, $i
     }
}' file.csv

Record # 1  =======>
Field # 1, value=[row1value1]
Field # 2, value=[row1value2]
Field # 3, value=[row1
multi
line
value]
Record # 2  =======>
Field # 1, value=[row2value1]
Field # 2, value=[row2value2]
Field # 3, value=[row2
multi
line
value]
```

However, as I commented above a dedicated CSV parser using PHP, Perl or Python will be more robust for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bash solution. The `multiline_csv.sh` script translates the multiline csv into standard csv by replacing the newline characters between quotes with some replacement string. So the usage is

`./multiline_csv.sh CSVFILE SEP`

I placed your example script in a file called `./multi.csv`. Running the command `./multiline_csv.sh ./multi.csv "\n"` yielded the following output

```
[ericthewry@eric-arch-pc stackoverflow]$ ./multiline_csv.sh ./multi.csv "\n"
r1c2,r1c2,"row1\nmulti\nline\nvalue"
r2c1,r2c2,"row2\nmultiline\nvalue"
```

This can be easily translated back to the original csv file using `printf`:

```
[ericthewry@eric-arch-pc stackoverflow]$ printf "$(./multiline_csv.sh ./multi.csv "\n")\n"
r1c2,r1c2,"row1
multi
line
value"
r2c1,r2c2,"row2
multiline
value"
```

This might be an Arch-specific quirk of echo/sprintf (I'm not sure), but you could use some other separator string like `~~~++??//NEWLINE\\??++~~~` that you could `sed` out if need be.

```
# multiline_csv.sh

open=0

line_is_open(){
    quote="$2"
    (printf "$1" | sed -e "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g") | (while read char; do
    if [[ "$char" = '"' ]]; then
        open=$((($open + 1) % 2))
    fi
    done && echo $open)
}


cat "$1" | while read ln ; do
    flatline="${ln}"

    open=$(line_is_open "${ln}" $open)

    until [[ "$open" = "0" ]]; do
    if read newln
    then
        flatline="${flatline}$2${newln}"
        open=$(line_is_open "${newln}" $open)
    else
        break
    fi

    done

    echo "${flatline}"
done
```

Once you've done this translation, you can proceed as you would normally via the `while read $ROW do ... done` method.